# haskell - function with lists involving Maybe not working

Tags: list, function, haskell, option-type

I have the following function:

```
-- xs: list to be changed
-- ws: list of indices where the values will change to 0
replaceAtIndices xs ws = [if (fromJust (elemIndex x xs)) `elem` ws then 0 else x | x <- xs]
```

The function takes in 2 lists. ws are the indices of the values in xs that I want to change to 0.

For some reason, it works for some cases, and not for others:

```
*Main> replaceAtIndices [1,2,3,4] [2,3]
```

[1,2,0,0] -- correct

```
*Main> replaceAtIndices [1,2,3,4] [2]
```

[1,2,0,4] -- correct

```
*Main> replaceAtIndices [1,1,2,1,3] [3]
```

[1,1,2,1,3] -- SHOULD be [1,1,2,0,3]

Can anyone please explain why this is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited the title because the question has nothing to do with the Monad interface; `Maybe` is just a data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elemIndex` returns the index of the *first* occurrence of the item in the list, so in the third case it always returns `0` for the index of `1` which doesn't match `3` so nothing gets replaced.

A better way of associating indexes with the items is to use `zip`:

```
replaceAtIndices xs ws = [if i `elem` ws then 0 else x | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs]
```

Comment: Thanks! This also gets rid of having to use Monads!